# VGG16 Keras Getting very low accuracy(~2%), while simple LeNet achieves up to 98%

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, vgg-net

I have been trying to train a VGG16 net in keras with a data set of about 2000 images. The problem occurs when consistently after each epoch I achieve a very low accuracy of around 2 percent, and it remains and fluctuates around that number. But when I train it with a simple leNet, it achieves a high accuracy of around 99 percent. I do not know what the problem is. Is there an inherent flaw in my code? Does more depth sometimes negatively affect your accuracy? Both pieces of code are attached below. Sorry, I do not have a screen shot of the training process.

VGG16 Code:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, input_shape = (224,224, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(128, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Conv2D(128, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(256, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Conv2D(256, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Conv2D(256, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(512, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Conv2D(512, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Conv2D(512, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(512, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Conv2D(512, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Conv2D(512, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(4096, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(4096, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(1000, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 30, activation = 'softmax'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.25)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/home/aslt/signData/top30Classes',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size= 15,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training')

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/home/aslt/signData/top30Classes',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size= 15,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation')

filePath="/home/aslt/modelFiles/callbacksVGGNetWeights.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filePath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1,     save_best_only=True, mode='max')
classifier.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples,
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples,
    epochs = 10,
    callbacks = [checkpoint])



classifier.save('aslModelVGG.h5')
```

LeNet Code:

```
import keras
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (64,64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(1000, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 30, activation = 'softmax'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.25)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/home/aslt/signData/top30Classes',
    target_size=(64, 64),
    batch_size= 15,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training')

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/home/aslt/signData/top30Classes',
    target_size=(64, 64),
    batch_size= 15,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation')
filepath="/home/aslt/modelFiles"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1,     save_best_only=True, mode='max')
classifier.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples,
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples,
    epochs = 10,
    callbacks = [checkpoint])



classifier.save('aslModelLeNet.h5')
```

Also, to be clear I am using a dataset from the hand speak dictionary. I split the videos into images. The goal is to be able to recognize American Sign Language words through image classification.

Comment: and there are 30 classes

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: I am wondering the reason why I am receiving such low accuracy. First, I would like to know if it is the code that causes me to receive this accuracy. Second, I am currently competing in the science fair and would like to present all my data. As I present my data, I want to know why it has such a low accuracy in comparison to the leNet if it is not the code.

Comment: Its most likely due to the size of the network. The first network is pretty large and will need more than 10 epochs for training. Also, you may be using the same architecture as VGG16 but you did not load the pretrained weights. Maybe look [here](https://keras.io/applications/)

Comment: Ok thank you! Sorry this is my first time implementing CNNs into code, is it possible if you can explain to me what the pre-trained weights do? @KurtisStreutker

Comment: and how would I go about this?

Comment: @NikhilChandra The weights of a neural network are initialized randomly when it is created and require training before they are useful. However, training on big networks like this takes quite a bit of time. Using pretrained weights allows you to speed up this process by using the weights from somebody that has already done the training process. Even though they have trained the network for a different task, the network will learn quicker for your data because it already knows how to extract various features from the images.